# mysqli_query will not update database, but does not return an error

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

I'm trying to update a database from an excel spreadsheet using phpexcel. Everything seems to run normally but the database remains empty.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","PIX");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
echo $con->host_info . "\n<br><br";

/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
$fileName = "Highlights.xls";
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileName);
$objReader->setReadDataOnly();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$allDataInSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet); // Total Number of rows in the uploaded EXCEL file
echo $arrayCount."<br>";

for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
  $string = '"'."INSERT INTO data (`pixName`) VALUES ";
  $pixName= trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);

  $string .= "('".$pixName."')".'"';
  echo $string."<br>";
  mysqli_query ($con, $string);
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Now, I find it weird because I checked the value of $string and it is what it's supposed to be:

> "INSERT INTO data (pixName) VALUES ('20091202tbg001')"

I do not have any error message but nothing appears in my database.
What am I not seeing here?

Thank you all so much for your time.

Comment: You never check for errors after executing the insert statement

Comment: `mysqli_query ($con, $string) or die(mysqli_error($con));` put it and check once

Comment: update your line: mysqli_query ($con, $string) or die(mysqli_error($con); it will show the error

Comment: Also add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);` juset after `<?php` and check

Comment: Dudanesk  check the answers below and mark and up-vote the answer which is most perfect for you. Thanks

Comment: 12 hours to check some 4-5 lines. it's bad. wastage of effort and time. deleting my stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
  $string = "INSERT INTO data (`pixName`) VALUES ";
  $pixName= trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);

  $string .= "('".$pixName."')";
  echo $string."<br>";
  mysqli_query ($con, $string);
}
```

Your mistake is adding **"(double quotes)** in this query

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to add "..." quotes in query. Just remove it and check

```
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
  $string = "INSERT INTO data (`pixName`) VALUES "; // Removed quotes 
  $pixName= trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);

  $string .= "('".$pixName."')"; // Removed quotes 
  echo $string."<br>";
  mysqli_query ($con, $string);
}
```